# Controlling Media Player in Visual Basic with WMPLib (or other)

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player

I need to get the current song in Windows Media Player, preferably using the wmp.dll library. There's documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563069%28v=VS.85%29.aspx but none of the resources I've tried have worked, even though I referenced the DLL and imported. A short example would be greatly appreciated as I'm getting nowhere at the moment.
Note that I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express

Comment: It would be really good if you posted the code that you've tried as an edit, so that people here can see what's not working and try to help you. It's difficult to help from a blank slate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the documentation provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also, maybe [this](http://stereoclood.codeplex.com/) Codeplex project may help you getting started. It uses WMPlib to play some songs.